# NodeJS prompt customization

Tags: javascript, node.js, prompt

I need to remove "prompt:" line on cmd. How can I do?
Example code:

```
prompt.start();
prompt.get([{name: 'username', required: true}], function (err, result) { if (err) { return onErr(err); }
    console.log('Your username: ' + result.username);
});
```

OUTPUT:

```
prompt: username:
```

I don't want prompt:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the prompt.message property falsey, like so:

```js
prompt.message = null;

prompt.start();
prompt.get([{name: 'username', required: true}], function (err, result) { if (err) { return onErr(err); }
    console.log('Your username: ' + result.username);
});
```

As documented in the [Customizing Your Prompt section of the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt#customizing-your-prompt)